# Integer alignment when printing

Tags: integer, text-alignment

Just expecting to print some result, can't get quite what the trace back is telling me

This temporary code gives some expected result:

```
input='55 + 1'
chopped=input.split()
minus_exists=input.find('+')
plus_exists=input.find('-') 

if  plus_exists ==-1:  
    chop_int1=int(chopped[0]) 
    chop_int2=int(chopped[2])
    max_chop=max(len(chopped[0]), len(chopped[2])) 
    dashes= max_chop+2 
    answer= chop_int1+chop_int2
    outstring=[chopped[0], chopped[1],chopped[2],f"{'-'*dashes : <{dashes}}",answer]
    
 
    print(f"{outstring[0]:>{dashes+1}}",'\n',f"{chop_int2:> {dashes}}",'\n' ,f"{outstring[3] : >{dashes}}",'\n',f"{outstring[4] : >{dashes}}")
```

When I change the value chop_int2 for outstring[2], it automatically prompts a traceback. I'm using other values from the table outstring and yet there's no error there.
Here's the change so that you can copy and paste into your console:

```
input='55 + 1'
chopped=input.split()
minus_exists=input.find('+')
plus_exists=input.find('-') 

if  plus_exists ==-1:  
    chop_int1=int(chopped[0]) 
    chop_int2=int(chopped[2])
    max_chop=max(len(chopped[0]), len(chopped[2])) 
    dashes= max_chop+2 
    answer= chop_int1+chop_int2
    outstring=[chopped[0], chopped[1],chopped[2],f"{'-'*dashes : <{dashes}}",answer]
    
 
    print(f"{outstring[0]:>{dashes+1}}",'\n',f"{outstring[2]:> {dashes}}",'\n' ,f"{outstring[3] : >{dashes}}",'\n',f"{outstring[4] : >{dashes}}")
```

Another fact that I don't know yet is how come I have to add 1 at the 1st print ( outstring[0]) so that it keeps being aligned with the rest of the following prints. These don't have +1 and yet the alignment is the same and the one I expected it to be.

Cheers,